# Squeryl JDK 1.8

Tags: scala, java-8, squeryl

We recently hit the same issue as discussed here - [Squeryl fails to reflect in debug mode only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666490/squeryl-fails-to-reflect-in-debug-mode-only)

And it was also solved by changing to use JDK 1.7

As Java 7 support life-cycle has ended; we would like to move to Java 8.

Does squeryl support Java 8?
Is there a solution to the `'error while reflecting on metadata'` issue?
Are there any other migration considerations?

Thanks,
Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question on the squeryl group and got

Does squeryl support Java 8? 
Yes; it should work on Java 8 <- mostly I was looking to confirm that in theory it should

Is there a solution to the 'error while reflecting on metadata' issue?
Kenji's link might be a lead to investigate this further; but till now I don't have an update

Are there any other migration considerations?
None were mentioned on the group

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is same issue in salat, lift-json. see https://github.com/novus/salat/issues/133